# Hoogle data on Windows

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I can install hoogle using `cabal install hoogle` on Windows, however, when I run `hoogle data` from MinGW shell, I encounter the following error:

```
$ hoogle data
Extracting tarball...
gzip: ..\hackage-cabal.tar.gz: No such file or directory
hoogle.exe: System command failed: gzip --decompress --force ..\hackage-cabal.ta
r.gz
```

How can I install hoogle easily on Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you don't have MinGW or Cygwin version's gzip in your path, if you install Windows version Git, you have MinGW installed by default, this will cause your gzip starts in the wrong directory, thus you may see the error:

> No such file or directory

Use the installer version of the Windows compatible binary (all the binaries will be installed within one directory by default), and add the binary to windows path variable.

wget:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/wget/1.11.4-1/wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe/download

gzip: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/gzip/1.3.12-1/gzip-1.3.12-1-setup.exe/download

tar: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/tar/1.13-1/tar-1.13-1-bin.exe/download

Comment: This is a shame. Packages should be OS agnostic, especially for elementary things like downloading and extracting files.

Comment: Also, I think just putting the wget/gzip/tar gnu versions in the path AHEAD of the Git path entries will suffice. This way you can still keep your git working from command line.

Answer (score 2):

To further clarify the answers given, what's going on is that hoogle internally is using windows paths while msys is making it see its view of the filesystem, resulting in hoogle being confused. To have this not happen fire up powershell, the windows version of the command line, and run hoogle data from there. You will need to have the GnuWin32 versions of wget, gzip and tar as mentioned by Sawyer. Once you've generated the data you will be able to use hoogle from msys without problem, though if later on you run hoogle data again you will still have to do it from powershell.

Answer (score 1):

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html  has everything you'll need.

I went through this myself last week.